# how to get averages of values in columns for each value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[2019-08, 2019-08, 2019-09, 2019-09, 2019-10, 2019-10], 'Name':['A','B','A','C', 'A', 'B'], 'math':[100,90,69,80,0,70], 'science':[100,90,0,80,92,95]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I want to iterate through the data and find the math and science grades per person per month.
My desired output should look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C'], 'math':[56.3333, 80, 69], 'science':[64, 92.5, 80]})
```

To be more clear, here are the steps I want to take.

```
1) get a Name (ex. A) 
2) get math grades for that person (100, 69, 0)
3) calculate the average (56.333)
4) get science grades for that person (100, 0, 92) 
5) calculate the average (64)
6) repeat the steps for every name (b and c)
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Name')[['math', 'science']].mean()`?

Answer (score 0):

Group them by 'name' and calculate the average for each

```
df.groupby('Name')[['math','science']].mean()
    math    science
Name        
A   56.333333   64.0
B   80.000000   92.5
C   80.000000   80.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'groupby' feature:

```
grp_grade=df.groupby(by='Name')

grp_grade.mean()
Out[17]: 
           math  science
Name                    
A     56.333333     64.0
B     80.000000     92.5
C     80.000000     80.0
```